# How do I print out each directory but as a pathname? (Explained in body description)

Tags: c, recursion, directory

This is a code written by Lloyd Macrohon and all credit belongs to him, but for the past two days I have been trying to modify this code such that instead of showing a list of each item in the directory I want to modify it such that it shows each item as a long pathname.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void listdir(const char *name, int indent)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            printf("%*s[%s]\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
            listdir(path, indent + 2);
        } else {
            printf("%*s- %s\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void) {
    listdir(".", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Above here is the original code which upon running in a unix terminal would output something like :

```
-file
[directory]
    [directory]
        -file
    -file
    -file
    ....
```

But instead I'm trying to run it like:

```
file
directory/directory/file
directory/file
directory/file
...
```

I my version of the code I have already removed the intends and I replaced them with a char which holds a character which should be the path-name up till the file.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void listdir(const char *name,const char *pname)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    char pathn = pname;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            //printf("%s/", entry->d_name);
            pathn = pathn + entry->d_name;
            listdir(path,pathn);
        }
        else if( pathn != ""){
          printf("%s and  %s ", pathn, entry->d_name);
        }
        else {
            printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void) {
  listdir(".","");
    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: Also please excuse any regulations that I may have missed, I'm not aware should it be illegal or against the rules to modify/upload other users codes without their permission, I am still rather new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you don't print the `name` passed to function?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void listdir(const char *name, int indent)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            //printf("%*s[%s]\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
            listdir(path, indent + 2);
        } else {
            printf("%s/%s\n", name, entry->d_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main() {
    system("mkdir -p dir/dir; touch dir/file dir/dir/file");
    listdir(".", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Live code available at [onlinedbg](https://onlinegdb.com/rJHr-mO57).